# Requiring a module that uses the revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying the `require` a module that is a self invoking Javascript function, and passing it a parameter when I `require` it.  The 'required' object is always saying 'object is not a function'.

Is the following code possible, and if so where I am going wrong?

Module

```js
var _ = require('lodash');

var userRepository = (function(userRecords) {

  console.log(userRecords);

  var findByUsername = function(username, cb) {

    //find username in the userNameData
    //this may have been retrieved from the DB or passed in as mock data from the tests
    var user = _.find(userRecords, {
      "email": username
    });

    if (user) {
      return cb(null, user);
    } else {
      return cb(null, null);
    }
  };

  return {
    findByUserName: findByUsername
  };

})();

module.exports = userRepository;
```

Usage in code

```js
var userData = require('../test/data/users.json'),
  userRepository = require('../db/userRepository')(userData);


describe('User Repository', function() {
  describe('Find by username', function() {
    it('should return a user record for <user> if the username <username> is found', function() {
      var username = "test@testing.com";
      var user = userRepository.findByUsername(username, function() {});
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userRepository` is an IIFE, which returns an object, so when you require it, you receive this object - which, alas, is not a function.

I see you're trying to invoke `findByUserName`, which is indeed a "public" function on this object, just change your require line to the following:

```
userRepository = require('../db/userRepository');
```

After this line, `userRepository` will be the object your IIFE returned. Then you can call `userRepository.findByUserName()` (as you are in your sample) without any further modifications to your code.

If you want `userRepository` to take `userRecord` as a parameter (as per your comment), don't use a self-invoking function, just export the function that's currently self-invoking.

*(Intuitively: if you want `userRecord` to be supplied from outside the module, you can't have this function self-invoke, you need to export the function itself to make it available to users of your module - so that they can call it with the `userRecord` that they have.)*

Comment: I'd like to pass a parameter to the `require` though. i.e. I want to pass the `userRecords` in (a bit like dependency injection).  This is so I can make the module more testable.  Is it possible to do this?  Thanks

Comment: @JonHunter Then don't make it a self-executing function, export the function which returns this object. (If you need `userRepository` to come from an outside source, you can't call this function inside your module, so it shouldn't be self-invoking) [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 2):

You can change you module declaration to function isntead

```
var userRepository = function(userRecords) {
  //private props

  return {
    //return object
  };

};
```

then it can be invoked with syntax you use - `require(MODULE_NAME)(data)`;

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is currently set up, you are exporting `userRepository`, which is actually equal to the return value of your anonymous function `{findByUserName: findByUsername}`. This explains why you are getting the error `Object is not a function`.

If you want your `require` to accept a parameter, it would have to be a function and not an object.